# Populating div with images from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I am trying to display some images from an array using JavaScript and jQuery.

Here is my container:

```
<div class="deck" id="card-deck">
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var masks = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];

for (var i = 0; i < masks.length; i++) {
    $(".deck").append('<span>' + masks[i] + '</span>');
}
```

The div gets populated, but with string text, which is normal, how does one display the images he has stored in an array properly? I need them in an array because later I will shuffle them etc.

Comment: `<img src="./${masks[i]}"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

```
const deck = $(".deck"); // only select this once if possible
masks.forEach(mask => deck.append('<img src=./' + mask + '>));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `img` tag insted of `span`.

```js
var masks = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];

for (var i = 0; i < masks.length; i++) {
    $(".deck").append('<img src="./'+masks[i]+'"/>');
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deck" id="card-deck">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without cancer:

```js
var masks = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];

masks.forEach(src => {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.title = src; // To tell them apart.
    window["card-deck"].appendChild(img);
});
```

```html
<div class="deck" id="card-deck">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $cardDeck = $("#card-deck");

var imgUrls = [
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940"
];


for (var i = 0; i < imgUrls.length; i++) {
   var $card = $("<div>", {"id":"card"});
    // using urls, but you can easily adjust this line and the imgUrls array to use image files
    $card.css("background-image", "url(" + imgUrls[i] + ")");
    $cardDeck.append($card);
}
```

```css
#card-deck {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: #0f0;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#card {
  width: 10em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deck" id="card-deck">
</div>
```